# Does halide support ARMv8(aarch64) with neon?

Tags: arm64, neon, halide

I'd like to use Halide for ARM A53(aarch64) target with neon vectorization.

But I cannot figure out how to create Target object. Also I cannot find aarch64 target with neon feature in [Target.h](https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/auto_scheduler/src/Target.h#L39).

The below code I've tested runs on A53 target but the generated code does not contain neon instructions.

```cpp
Target target("arm-64-linux"); // is it right?
Buffer<uint16_t> input(640,480);

Var x,y;
Func brighter("brighter");
brighter(x,y) = input(x,y) + 100;
brighter.estimate(x, 0, 640).
         estimate(y, 0, 480);

Pipeline p(brighter);
p.auto_schedule(target);
p.compile_to_static_library("./lib_dummy", {input}, "", target);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

arm-64 is what Halide uses for aarch64, so your target is fine. To use neon instructions, you need to be vectorizing something. Not sure if the autoscheduler is doing that or not (it should be!). Try not autoscheduling and instead just saying:

```
brighter.vectorize(x, 8);
```

Comment: still cannot see the neon instructions even if using brighter.vectorize instread of auto_schedule().

Comment: My mistake! I was searching arm 32 instructions instead of ARMv8 instructions. The binary contains ARMv8 instructions.